# Kubernetes rolling update without downtime?

Tags: kubernetes, patch, downtime, kubernetes-statefulset, live-update

According to https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#scaling-a-statefulset, I would like to ask how to achieve zero-downtime rolling update? I guess here are the minimum requirements:

(1) .spec.updateStrategy set to RollingUpdate

(2) .spec.podManagementPolicy set to OrderedReady

(3) .spec.replicas set to 2

Is that right? And I assume that when update is happening in reverse order, all traffic to the StatefulSet is served by the  pods with lower ordinal number?

Answer (score 7):

Yes to have have zero downtime for `statefulsets` upgrade, you should have all the points mentioned:

1. `.spec.updateStrategy` set to `RollingUpdate`
2. `.spec.podManagementPolicy` set to `OrderedReady` which is by default `OrderedReady`
3. `.spec.replicas` set to minimum 2.

Another, thing you need to make sure your statefulset doesn't have downtime is proper `readiness` probe set. The `readiness` probe tells kubernetes controller manager that this pod is ready to serve request and you can start sending the requests to it.

The reason it is very important while doing zero downtime upgrade is lets say you have two replica's of statefulset and you started rolling upgrade without readiness probe set. The kubernetes will delete the pod in reverse order and make it come to running state and mark it as ready and terminate another pod. Now lets say your container process didn't come up in that time there will be no pod to serve the requests, because one pod is not completely ready yet and kubernetes has terminated another pod for upgrade process and hence the data loss.

```
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /
    port: 80
  initialDelaySeconds: 5
  periodSeconds: 5
  successThreshold: 1
```

EDIT: The following json snippet I use for rolling update of statefulsets in my case:

```
 "spec": {
         "containers": [
           {
             "name": "md",
             "image": "",
             "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
             "command": [
               "/bin/sh",
               "-c"
             ],
             "args": [
               "chmod -R 777 /logs/; /on_start.sh"
             ],
             "readinessProbe": {
                "exec": {
                   "command": [
                      "cat",
                      "/tmp/ready.txt"
                   ]
                 },
                 "failureThreshold": 10,
                 "initialDelaySeconds": 5,
                 "periodSeconds": 5,
                 "successThreshold": 1,
                 "timeoutSeconds": 1
             },
             "securityContext": {
               "privileged": true
             }
      }
```

This is how you can setup readiness probe in your statefulset containers. I am setting readiness probe as `linux command`, if you have http probe then it will be different.

Comment: Please go through following link to understand how to do zero downtime upgrade https://medium.com/platformer-blog/enable-rolling-updates-in-kubernetes-with-zero-downtime-31d7ec388c81

Comment: These parameters are only applicable to Deployment. Not StatefulSet.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can use readiness probe in statefulset also. I have added snippet which I use for upgrade my statefulsets

Comment: According to https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/294, those parameters are not for StatefulSet, only for Deployment..?

Comment: You can not set `maxUnavailable` and `maxSurge` parameter in rollingupdate strategy are not for statefulsets. The parameter I mentioned in readiness probe are present for statefulsets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187241/discussion-between-prafull-ladha-and-kok-how-teh).

Comment: No, readiness probe params are also not available for statefulsets...:(

Comment: Hi, sorry the params are available. I made a mistake in the indentations of the params that caused the syntax error.

Comment: Now, did you tried upgrading the rolling update of statefullsets using the readiness parameter, so that if statefulsets will be upgrading replicas one by one and start the next replica only if the previous upgraded replica is ready to serve requests

Comment: It still doesn't work due to this bug: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/74456 Do you have the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Prafull Ladha, the main role of `readinessProbe` here to guarantee that the new pods created during `RollingUpdate` are ready to take on requests before terminating the old pods.
However, you can also control the rolling update process by specifying the appropriate optional parameters as described in official Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#rolling-update-deployment).

Comment: These parameters are only applicable to Deployment. Not StatefulSet.

Comment: yeah, you are right for statefulsets it's not applicable, just only [Partitions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#partitions) .